# Show that if $f''(x)=-k^2f(x)$, then $f(x)= A \sin (kx) + B \cos (kx)$

Tags: derivatives

Show that if $f''(x)=-k^2 f(x)$, then $f(x)= A \sin (kx) + B \cos (kx)$

Comment: Please check for typos.

Comment: This isn't true. Let $f(x)=e^{kx}+e^{-kx}$, for all $x\in \mathbb R$. 

It comes $f'(x)=ke^{kx}-ke^{-kx}$ and $f''(x)=k^2e^{kx}+k^2e^{-kx}=k^2f(x)$. If you meant $f''(x)=-k^2f(x)$, it's still not true.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about gibberish

Comment: @WillJagy You're the funniest guy on MSE.

Comment: @GitGud, I do make an effort. i feel i owe it to my fans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking you mean $-k$ real, $$\frac{d^2 f}{d x^2}= -k^2f \Longleftrightarrow \frac{d^2 f}{d x^2}+ k^2f=0$$

This is a Linear ODE (Ordinary Differential Equation) so we just solve its characteristic equation:
Assume$$ f(x)=C e^{mx}$$
$\Longrightarrow$ which by differentiation gives $$\frac{d^2 f}{d x^2}=m^2Ce^{mx}$$

Substituting $f$ and $f''$ into the ODE gives $$(m^2+k^2)C e^{mx}=0$$

We assume that $C \neq 0$ and we know that $\forall m,\quad e^{mx} \neq 0$

So we must have
$$m^2+k^2=0$$
This gives $$m=\pm \sqrt{-k^2}=\pm ik$$ for

Replacing $m$ in line 2 (which we assumed) and remembering that there are two values for $m$ gives $f(x)$ to have form $$f(x) = \alpha e^{ikx} + \beta e^{-ikx}$$ with $\alpha, \beta$ constant.

We are almost done! just change $$e^{ikx}=\cos{kx}+i\sin{kx}$$ and $$e^{-ikx}=\cos{kx}-i\sin{kx}$$ to get 
$$f(x)=(\alpha + \beta)\cos{kx}+i(\alpha - \beta)\sin{kx} $$
and just define $B=(\alpha + \beta)$ and $A=i(\alpha - \beta)$
So this results in $$f(x)=A\sin{kx}+B\cos{kx}$$